# Loop n-times on DOS 6.22

Tags: batch, shell-script, ms-dos

`FOR /L %%parameter IN (start,step,end) DO command` does not work on `DOS 6.22`.

The `/L` argument to loop through a set of numbers is not available in `DOS 6.22`.

`FOR` in `DOS 6.22` can merely loop through a set of files. Any workaround with builtin tools?

---

On *nix systems this is no big thing for me, but I try to do that on a retro laptop with Win 3.1 with DOS 6.22 as stated in the question:

[Securely erase empty disk space on a Win 3.1 / DOS 6.22 system with builtin tools](https://superuser.com/questions/1160453/)

Comment: I was going to suggest using `goto` and `set` with arithmetic but I don't think arithmetic is supported in DOS 6.22

Comment: Please provide more information about your specific problem - it may be that a "loop n times" solution may not be the best/most appropriate solution, even if it turns out to be the most obvious (and easiest to implement on other systems).

Comment: My specific problem is described in the link provided at the end of my post, which is another SuperUser thread. Wanted to avoid duplication. Wanted to separate the issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own INC.BAT and use it like

**test.bat**

```
@echo off
set count=0
:loop
call inc.bat %count% count
echo %count%
if not %count%==15 goto :loop
```

**INC.BAT**

```
@echo off

for %%L in (%0) do if "%%L"=="/" goto %1

REM Split and reverse number into _valueRev
set _remain=%1
set _valueRev=

:split_loop
set _loop=1

for %%a in (/%_remain%) do call %0// :split %1 %%a
if NOT "%_remain%"=="" goto :split_loop
goto :increment

:split
if %_loop%==2 goto :split_2
set _loop=2
set _remain=
set _valueRev=%3,%_valueRev%
goto :eof

:split_2
set _remain=%3
goto :eof

REM The main increment function
:increment
set _result=
set _carry=1
for %%d in (%_valueRev%) do call %0// :incDig %%d
if not "%_carry%"=="" call %0// :incDig 0

if NOT "%2"=="" set %2=%_result%
echo %_result%
REM Clear temp vars
FOR %%v in (_result _carry _loop _valueRev _valueRev_comma _digit _remain) do set %%v=
goto :eof

:incDig
set _digit=%2
if "%_carry%"=="" goto :endinc
set _carry=
if %2==9 set _digit=0
if %2==9 set _carry=1
if %2==8 set _digit=9
if %2==7 set _digit=8
if %2==6 set _digit=7
if %2==5 set _digit=6
if %2==4 set _digit=5
if %2==3 set _digit=4
if %2==2 set _digit=3
if %2==1 set _digit=2
if %2==0 set _digit=1

:endinc
set _result=%_digit%%_result%
:eof
```